# Is it possible to get all the coordinates of a certain address in Android GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible? like when i put a string address, all the coordinates of that area will appear in a list?

if Yes, can you tell how?

if No, Is there another way of doing that?

If still No, is there a app or a website that can display all the coordinates of a certain address?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);  
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("addressName", 100); // maxResults = 100
for(Address address : addresses){
   double latitude= address.getLatitude();
   double longitude= address.getLongitude();
}
```